# Set tinymce editor content as readonly in angular 4

Tags: angular, tinymce, angular4-forms

I have two editors in my form. I am using angular 4. I have applied the following code to set the editor as readonly:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().style.backgroundColor = '#ecf0f5';
```

But from the above code, only one editor content set as readonly. How to perform this on all editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of all the editors on the page with

```
tinymce.editors
```

This returns an array with references to each editor.  You can then iterate over the array and perform those commands on each editor instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply disable the editor:

```html
<editor [disabled]="someCondition"></editor>
```

Comment: disabled and readonly are two different things. Readonly allows you to select the text, but not change it. Disabled prevents you from doing anything with the control, even selecting text.

Comment: I'm using `disabled` in my project and I can still select the text and scroll through it.

Comment: interesting! Can you tell me what version of tinymce you're using that behaves that way? Maybe I did something wrong. If you can select the text, can you do with with ctrl-a, or do you need to use the mouse? Does it allow you to press ctrl-c to copy the text once it's selected?

Comment: I just tried, I can copy text, and if I do ctrl+a, it selects the whole editor content :) Using `@tinymce/tinymce-angular 4.2.0` and `tinymce 5.6.2`

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea from @Michel's answer and wrote the following code:

```
var result = tinymce.editors;
      result.forEach(element => {
        tinymce.get(element.id).getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
        tinymce.get(element.id).getBody().style.backgroundColor = '#ecf0f5';
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like others have success disabling the control. When I tried, it wouldn't allow any keyboard or mouse interaction. So instead, I used this approach, which worked well for me, which allows ctrl/a, ctrl/c and mouse selection, but prevents the user from editing the text.

```
tinyInitROI: any = {
base_url: '/hvbi/tinymce',
suffix: '.min',
resize: true,
plugins: "autoresize fullscreen print preview",
autoresize_bottom_margin: 10,
menubar: false,
toolbar: 'selectall copy print fullscreen',
fullscreen_native: true,

setup: function (editor) {
  editor.on('keydown', function (e, evt) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.key == 'a' || e.key == 'c' || e.key == 'Control')) {
      return;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }),
  editor.on('contextmenu', function (e, evt) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

}